# How to update Array using $.each in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I have an array parsed using `JSON.parse()` given below.

```
var b = [{"pk":"1","name":"Ali","marked":"N" },
{"pk":"2","name":"Zeeshan","marked":"N" },
{"pk":"3","name":"Tariq","marked":"N" }]
```

This list contains roughly 4000 records, Now I want to update `marked = "Y"` where `pk` is in [2,3].
`pk` list length could be 100. My question is, how could we iterate over b and set `marked="Y"` where `pk` is in listed values ?

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: I have shown parsed array.

Comment: Yes, but the point is by the time you're marking those entries, you're not dealing with JSON, so JSON is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `$.each` in the modern world, arrays have `forEach` and such (which you can shim if you really need to support obsolete browsers like IE8).

If `pk` can have 100 entries and you're filtering 4,000 records, I'd build a map of `pk` values and use that. Here's an ES5 approach:

```js
var b = [
  {"pk":"1","name":"Ali","marked":"N" },
  {"pk":"2","name":"Zeeshan","marked":"N" },
  {"pk":"3","name":"Tariq","marked":"N" }
];
var pk = ["2", "3"];

// Build the "map"
var map = Object.create(null);
pk.forEach(function(value) {
  map[value] = true;
});

// Mark relevant entries
b.forEach(function(entry) {
  if (map[entry.pk]) {
    entry.marked = "Y";
  }
});
console.log(b);
```

This avoids constantly calling `pk.indexOf(entry.pk)` to see if an entry should be marked, which requires re-scanning the array each time. Instead, it leverages the JavaScript engine's object property lookup code, which is *highly* optimized on modern browsers (even unoptimized it would likely be some kind of hash map or similar, but they optimize these days).

If you **did** want to use `$.each` instead, just change

```
pk.forEach(function(value) {
```

to

```
$.each(pk, function(_, value) {
// Note ------------^
```

and the same for the `b` loop later. `$.each` calls the callback with the *index* of the entry as the first argument, and *then* the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var b = [
  {"pk":"1","name":"Ali","marked":"N" },
  {"pk":"2","name":"Zeeshan","marked":"N" },
  {"pk":"3","name":"Tariq","marked":"N" }
];
var condition = ["2", "3"];

$.each(b,function(index,value){
  if(condition.indexOf(value.pk) > -1){
     value.marked = "Y";
  }
});

console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```